# Why is the grub menu appearing when there is no dual-boot option?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, grub2

So I used to dual boot Ubuntu and windows 10. Now I'm commited to Ubuntu so I deleted the win partition and ran `update-grub`, but the grub menu is not gone yet. The entry for windows is gone, but right now it shows Ubuntu, Advanced options for ubuntu, memtest, and memtest+. Is this normal? Isn't this supposed to go away?
The output of `cat /etc/default/grub`:

```
# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
#   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

# Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
# This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains
# the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
#GRUB_TERMINAL=console

# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
#GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480

# Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true

# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
#GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"

# Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the two lines

```
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
```

to

```
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=menu
GRUB_TIMEOUT=0
```

and run `sudo update-grub` again.

Please take a look at the [GNU Grub Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/grub.html#Simple-configuration), here the relevant points:

```
‘GRUB_TIMEOUT’

    Boot the default entry this many seconds after the menu is displayed,
    unless a key is pressed. The default is ‘5’. Set to ‘0’ to boot
    immediately without displaying the menu, or to ‘-1’ to wait
    indefinitely.

    If ‘GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE’ is set to ‘countdown’ or ‘hidden’, the timeout
    is instead counted before the menu is displayed.
```

```
‘GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE’

    If this option is unset or set to ‘menu’, then GRUB will display the
    menu and then wait for the timeout set by ‘GRUB_TIMEOUT’ to expire
    before booting the default entry. Pressing a key interrupts the timeout.

    If this option is set to ‘countdown’ or ‘hidden’, then, before
    displaying the menu, GRUB will wait for the timeout set by 
    ‘GRUB_TIMEOUT’ to expire. If ESC is pressed during that time, it will
    display the menu and wait for input. If a hotkey associated with a
    menu entry is pressed, it will boot the associated menu entry
    immediately. If the timeout expires before either of these happens, it
    will boot the default entry. In the ‘countdown’ case, it will show a
    one-line indication of the remaining time.
```

Grub also has some functions which might override the timeout set in `/etc/default/grub`:

- The filesystem which holds Grub's [Environment Block](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/grub.html#Environment-block) is not writable (due to filesystem corruption or lack of support)
- Boot failure (will override your settings only for next boot)
- Multiple Operating Systems (Dual boot)

Comment: For whatever reason, it works sometimes but sometimes it doesn't. Please help!

Comment: Ok, i change the timeout style to hidden and it works now!

Comment: From what I see, both options should work, either `GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden` or `GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=menu`, there might be other reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Change `GRUB_TIMEOUT=10` to `GRUB_TIMEOUT=0` in `/etc/default/grub` and type update-grub'''

Comment: Or you can install ```grub-customizer``` to set timeout to 0 without any comandline

Comment: Thanks! Gonna try `grub-customizer` now!